# svn merging specific files within revision range

Tags: svn, merge

I'm setting up SVN for an existing environment with a DEV codebase and a PROD codebase. DEV has a ton of pending changes so the codebases are significantly diverged.

I set up a TRUNK repo based of of prod. Then, I checked out that repo into DEV and committed to a new DEV branch.

So TRUNK looks like:
REV 1 - initial code import

and DEV looks like:
REV 1 - initial code import
REV 2 - adding dev changes

My problem is I would like to be able to merge changes from DEV to TRUNK for a specific set of files that are part of REV 2 for just those files.

In other words, let's say a developer finishes a project and commits FILE1 to DEV as REV3. But he was also working on FILE1 when I created the repos, so it was included in REV2. When he goes to merge from DEV to TRUNK opting for range of revisions, if he chooses
just REV3, he won't get all of his changes. But if he chooses REV2 and REV3, he will get all of the DEV changes for the other files that are not ready for PROD yet.

Hopefully, I'm making some sense here. How do I specify just certain files for a merge? Or is there another, better approach altogether?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you merge revisions, they take all changes included in them, so you don't have a straightforward way of doing what you are looking for.

You could

1. create a new branch off of trunk,
2. merge Rev3 into this branch's working directory,
3. revert the files you don't want included,
4. commit the changes to this branch
5. merge to trunk

If you follow the above steps, you will most likely have to deal with tree conflicts later on when you try to merge the Dev branch in full back to trunk.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I ended up creating a dev branch synched with prod, committed the historic dev changes, then reverted them just so they'd be in the repo. then left them as uncommited changes in an isolated working copy. does the job...